# Something similar to Stabilizers in Groups

Tags: group-theory

I am working on a Group Theory problem. It remains for me to show the following.

> Suppose $G$ is a group. $h$ is a finite order element in G. Then there exist $n>0$ such that for all $g$ in $G$, $g^nh=hg^n$.

I have little idea what does this really mean. Why raising $g$ to the $n$th power changes "something"? Can anyone offer me a proof and give some intuition why this is true?

Comment: Is that actually true?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I am 95 percent sure that it is true.

Comment: How can you be 95% sure that it's true? (It's not true. )

Comment: This is true if there are only finitely many elements of finite order. Where did you come across this problem?

Comment: (I cast the final vote-to-close as I feel context is important here, especially because the question, as posed, is incorrect. You should edit your question to include where you found the question, and any other relevant "meta" information.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Here's a counter-example: $\langle a,b\,\mid\,a^2=e\rangle$, i.e, the group generated by two elements, one of which is of order two.

In your hypotheses, $h$ corresponds to $a$. Now take $g=b$. No matter what $n>0$ you take, $ab^n\neq b^na$.

Comment: Why the -1 vote?